# missing libraries/dependencies since latest gazebo/ros/drcsim updates? (liburdfdom_model.so...)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I've been running gazebo with drcsim on Ubuntu 12.04 successfully for some months.
However since the latest package updates in the past few days, gazebo now crashes and reports missing libraries.
Are possibly some dependencies missing from the gazebo 1.3.1 package?

The error I get is:

```
$ gazebo
gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: liburdfdom_model.so: cannot open shared object file: >No such file or directory
```

I see the following of unresolved libs:

```
$ ldd $(which gazebo) | grep 'not found' | sort | uniq
    libOgreMain.so.1.7.3 => not found
    libOgreRTShaderSystem.so.1.7.3 => not found
    libOgreTerrain.so.1.7.3 => not found
    liburdfdom_model.so => not found
    liburdfdom_world.so => not found
```

I've tried uninstalling/purging/re-installing drcsim and gazebo with no success.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1139/missing-libraries/dependencies-since-latest-gazebo/ros/drcsim-updates?-(liburdfdom_model.so...)/) by [andyw](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/184/andyw/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I just realised my mistake:

It turns out I wasn't running the setup.sh file.
Sourcing either the gazebo or drcsim setup.sh file resolves the issue for me.

Thanks for the prompt response though! and I'm running from apt packages.

---

Originally posted by [andyw](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/184/andyw/) with karma: 16 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0